# Scale down PDF page size with Perl

Tags: perl, pdf

I process PDF files in an existing Perl framework. Some of the incoming files have very large page sizes. What I would like to do:

1. Check if the input file's page size is larger than a specific format `f` (A4/Letter)
2. If it is larger than `f`: scale it down to `f`.

This is the corresponding command in Unix using GhostScript:

```
gs -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -dFIXEDMEDIA -dPSFitPage -o <outputFile> -sDEVICE=pdfwrite <inputFile>
```

Is there a way to do this within Perl, i.e. without requiring to call external tools?
I checked the modules [PDF](http://search.cpan.org/~antro/PDF-111/PDF.pm) and [CAM::PDF](http://search.cpan.org/~cdolan/CAM-PDF-1.60/lib/CAM/PDF.pm), but the documentation does not really cover my issue and I couldn't find a straight-forward solution.

Comment: The PDF module has not been updated for 16 years. CAM::PDF might have it. I suggest you use [metacpan](https://metacpan.org/release/CAM-PDF) to browse it as that makes your life considerably easier. Check all the things it brings. I'm also pretty sure that PDF::API2 cannot do what you want.

Comment: This answer uses PDF::API2 to address a similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947925/how-to-add-header-footer-with-images-using-pdfapi2lite/3049803#3049803 Note that you can pass a scale to the `formImage` method